# Which function will return a recent date between two dates in query

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a personnel management system and would assistance on a function to calculate retirement year based on date of birth and date of joining. For example, an employee should retire after 35 tears in service or when he gets to the age of 65 year.

Comment: I am using Ms Access, so I wish to query the database to return a recent date

Comment: where is your work ?

Comment: Do you have your own code, or do you expect us to write a complete program for you?

Comment: ::Vote to Close:: This is to broad of a question, please provide a specific question of where you are experiencing difficulties.